# Heroku and Praw (Reddit API) submission.reply()

Tags: python, heroku, reddit, praw

I don't know if this is a problem with Heroku or not, but I hope you can help me guys.

I am building a bot in python using the praw library where I use the `submission.reply("something")` to comment some posts, but the thing is that it only works in my local machine.

When I upload it to Heroku, it does not work, except for a post in a certain subreddit and I am not entirely sure why. After that one, it simply does not comment anything. I tested it with try/except and the error is here for sure, but I can´t find the problem.

Here is the error:

> praw.exceptions.RedditAPIException: RATELIMIT: "Looks like you've been doing that a lot. Take a break for 3 minutes before trying again." on field 'ratelimit'

Comment: Please post more details about your code or the problem you are having. Where does the code stops ? What it can't do ? When it works ?

Comment: Thats the thing. It stops there. The problem must be there for sure. When it works, you ask? Locally only. My code is really simple: I pick the titles from some subreddits and check if they have a particular word. If yes, I make a reply. Everything is running fine in my computer, but when I use submission.reply(mytext) it does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your bot is commenting way too fast for the reddit API guidelines. Try adding a delay timer of about 10 seconds after every comment.